# Check-Button on Screen Rotate

Tags: android, checkbox, state, screen-rotation

I have a problem with a list of items, each one with a checkbox. Rotating the screen does not keep this button checked. My idea was to keep it with a viewModel and a boolean variable that in the viewModel was false and in the Fragment I have tried to change it to true in the onClick method of the checkbox but it still doesn't maintain the checked state. To clarify, I am doing this on the init method of a RecyclerView function. What's wrong with this solution?

Viewmodel:

```
var check:Boolean = false
```

Fragment:

```
private val instanceViewModel by lazy {
    activity?.run{
        ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ViewModel::class.java)
    }?:throw Exception(" ")
}
`Inside a class on the fragment

init{
    checkbox = view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox) as CheckBox

    ….

     checkbox.setOnClickListener{
    if(checkbox.isChecked){
        instanceViewModel.check = true
        texto.visibility = View.VISIBLE

    }
    else{
        instanceViewModel.check = false
        texto.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    }

}``
```

Comment: To help us help you, please show us the relevant parts of your code. We can't see what is wrong if we can't see what is happening.

Comment: I attach my code: In the viewModel:var checked:Boolean = false
In the Fragment:
…
private val instanceViewModel by lazy {
   activity?.run{
       ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ViewModel::class.java)
   }?:throw Exception(" ")
}
….
Inside a class on the fragment
init{
 checkbox = view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox) as CheckBox
 ...
  checkbox.setOnClickListener{
    if(checkbox.isChecked){
        instanceViewModel.check = true
        texto.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
    else{
        instanceViewModel.check = false
        texto.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    }